# Format datetime as UTC with strftime (for use in git)

Tags: bash, date, timestamps, timezone, git-log

I can format dates and time pretty flexibly with `strftime`, but from what I can see, this only will give times in my local timezone; I can add the timezone offset (e.g. `'%Y %m %d-%H:%M:%S%z'` for a particular time yields `2022 02 14 16:21:35-0800`), but what I actually want is the datetime for UTC. (For that example, `2022 02 15 00:21:35`.) Is this possible with `strftime`?

(Context: I'm fiddling with `git log --date=format` trying to get a format which matches `go.mod` fake versions. The `--date=format:'%foo%bar'` option, for defining custom formats, delegates to system `strftime`. I'm on Mac OSX Monterey and using bash. EDIT: Solution was somewhat more complex due to being used in git; changed the question description to reflect that.)

Comment: Note for anyone trying to duplicate the go.mod pseudo-version format; you want `--format=v0.0.0-%cd-%h\ %s --abbrev=12`, rather than using `%ad`. . . . . . My full alias, including the answer, is `TZ=UTC0 git log --date=format-local:'%Y%m%d%H%M%S' --format=v0.0.0-%cd-%h\ %s --abbrev=12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strftime()` C function only formats a date/time. You would pass it the result of `gmtime()` to get UTC time or `localtime()` to get the local time.

`date` displays the local time by default, but can be told to display UTC time with the `-u` option.

`localtime()` computes the local time from a given epoch time (like the value returned by `time()`) based on the contents of the `$TZ` environment variable which specifies the timezone. And if that variable is not defined, the behaviour varies between systems.

If you have tools that always display local time and cannot be told to switch to universal time, you can always call them in an environment where `$TZ` specifies a timezone with constant zero offset to UTC.

```
TZ=UTC0 date
```

Has the same effect as:

```
date -u
```

`TZ=UTC0` defines a locale called `UTC` that is of 0 offset to UTC, so you get UTC time and `date +%Z` gives you "UTC", so with that value of `$TZ`, `localtime()` behaves just like `gmtime()`.

For `git`'s `--date=format`, you also need to append `-local`, for the date to be expressed as local time instead of the timezone stored in the commit. So:

```
TZ=UTC0 git log --date=format-local:'%Y %m %d-%T'
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do anything here. `git log -1 --date=format:'%Y %m %d %H%z' 1e15a58a` hands me back `2022 01 24 17-0800`.  `TZ=UTC0 git log -1 --date=format:'%Y %m %d %H%z' 1e15a58a` hands me back the exact same string.

Comment: @jkmartin, see edit.

Comment: Ahah. Yes, that works. Thanks.